# Return type of a single property from type T in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a helper function that I'm porting from JavaScript:

```js
function extractDistinct(data, fieldName) {
  const uniques = data.reduce(
    (set, x) => set.add(x[fieldName]), new Set()
  );
  return [...uniques];
}
```

This function simplify extract a list of unique values for property `fieldName` in a an array of items. While the JavaScript code actually allows for a collection of possibly different data types —as long as they have the intended field— I guess the version I'm trying to get for TypeScript would limit to an array of a single type.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function extractDistinct<T>(data: T[], fieldName: keyof T): unknown[] {
  const uniques = data.reduce((set, x) => set.add(x[fieldName]), new Set());
  return [...uniques];
}
```

It works in that the TS compiler is checking to make sure `fieldName` is indeed a property of `T` but I have to cast the whole thing as the intended type which is a bit clunky:

```js
const people: Person[] = .... // doesn't matter where it comes from.
const hairColor = extractDistinct(people, 'hair_color') as string[]);
```

I currently have it as returning `unknown[]` but I'm trying to return the type declared for this key/field in type `T`. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `extractDistinct()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `K` of the `fieldName` parameter as well as in the type `T` of the elements of `data`, where `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T`:

```
function extractDistinct<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T[], fieldName: K): T[K][] {
  const uniques = data.reduce((set, x) => set.add(x[fieldName]), new Set<T[K]>());
  return [...uniques];
}
```

This uses the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]` to represent the property type of `T` at key `K`.  That compiles with no error, and now you get your desired behavior:

```
interface Person {
  hair_color: string;
  number_of_limbs: number;
  actually_three_hedgehogs_in_a_trenchcoat: boolean;
}
declare const people: Person[];

const hairColor = extractDistinct(people, 'hair_color');
// const hairColor: string[]

const numberOfLimbs = extractDistinct(people, 'number_of_limbs');
// const numberOfLimbs: number[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5QE4ENoBEYDOskUAPACoA0iA0iusmACYGIDWyAnnMIuQHwAKJlihYAXHwDaAXWrAYyADZMAclgC2ySTQCUk8lJozZiAN4AoRIggIiicDACOIZKwC8iEWIB0GZEwgEMiCggTIUNSouoju-IjhUD5YTEyCqFIKymqayDK61GDIAO6IAMoRFEYyQrq6ANxWiP5QIBhIUj5dji5uMo0AvhYWMGBQyBjAOMiIAAoTBAjmTQAWWDAYAPq2SnAYkkQYowDmjdZgIBoARhObPJtKMNcEkhfXE2eIOK1YSkqcmygK38yE2KwCx2QKzgxwIm1GmywgP8kBWtlEkiucDgSmQWDAgwsTGQECUWH8NjsUEQAAdkHAabjJPMMIswKYAPQcrxwNxgADk1I0onGGEQxXBFJg1NsWlYwAwcA0PgstjA9jWGwAwji9rF6JhvvgiKNoII6QzcdR+Zqtjs9vyGhYuZT1dTbTrdvsEpgTrJhmr7G8bhgAPLAAAyTyuHgN2DwhGIZotjOQ1uDt3uj2ejsaLsD1IzYcj0ZeiCLsiAA)

Comment: Sweeeeet! I had tried earlier with `<T, K keyof T>` but I was missing the `extend`. Ty ty ty!